# How to send email - SAPUI5

Tags: email, sapui5, sap-fiori

I am trying to send sample email in SAPUI5. I have used `sap.m.URLHelper.triggerEmail(["dummy@mail.com"], ["sample Subject"], ["Hi"]);`. But it is not working. I have also tried using `window.top.location = "mailto:" + email + "&subject=" + subject + "&body=" + message;`. But no luck.

[image: Below is what i am getting]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    sap.m.URLHelper.triggerEmail("dummy@mail.com", "sample Subject", "Hi");
```

It should be without the [ ] because the parameters that triggerEmail expects are of type string

Comment: @@Ajay I have tried but still the problem exists !!. I have added a screenshot to my question. Please refer.

Comment: Strange, it should work as Ajay mentioned... See this working example: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.UrlHelper/preview

Comment: @Qualiture same error occurs for this example too. I am running in incognito mode. Is this causes the problem??

Comment: That's strange indeed... it should just open the configured email client

Comment: @Qualiture I am using Outlook 2016. It is kept open. Still email is not opening

Comment: @Yal if you click on the email button in the example given in the link https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.UrlHelper/preview      Is it opening the configured email? If not what is the message you are receiving? can you open Developer tools and let me know the message in 'Red' you are seeing in the console?

Comment: @ajay-reddy No error occurred in console. Only in Network it shows some  error. I have updated my question. Please refer.

Comment: @Yal Paste this in your browser URL and let me know what happens?                               mailto:john.smith%40sap.com?subject=info%20Request

Comment: The `Upgrade-Insecure-Requests` header may be the issue related to Chrome, see https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/OrwppKWbKnc However, except for the 'cancelled' warning in the Network tab, I suspect the mail client is being opened just fine?

Comment: @AjayReddy If i paste this in browser, It does nothing.

Comment: It is working in other systems except mine. I think there might be some problem with the settings. I will resolve &  post the answer. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: @Yal Since it does nothing that means that your mail client is not setup properly in your system   Just set up the mail client properly and you should be good to go. Also after that please mark my solution as the answer since that is the correct solution without the [] and it will help others having the same problem

Comment: Yes it was setup configuration problem. Thanks !!